# Disable Windows Mobile security features

Tags: security, windows-mobile

I'm currently writing an app for a Windows Mobile 5.0 app and it seems to possess some firewall-esqe feature where I need to permit the running of any deployed executable. Is there some kind of registry key I can use to turn this off during development as it's frustrating having to babysit the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the [Device Security Powertoy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7e92628c-d587-47e0-908b-09fee6ea517a&displaylang=en)?

Answer (score 3):

In the Windows Mobile SDK, a configuration CPF file (like a CAB file, but for configuration only) is provided to disable the security settings on a device you are doing development on. Copy C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Tools\Smartphone\SecurityConfiguration\SecurityOff.cpf to your device and run it. You should then no longer see the prompts.

BTW: Sounds like you are talking about the 'Unsigned Prompt Policy' security policy. Here is a list of security policies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa455966.aspx